# <httpRedirect/> - match URL containing string

Tags: iis, web-config, http-redirect

I want to redirect every URL containing a particular string to https://example.com/. I am using IIS with [HTTP Redirect installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpRedirect/) and I have added a rule to my Web.config.

```
 <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
    <add wildcard="*" destination="https://example.com/" />
 </httpRedirect>
```

The problem is that `wildcard="*"` works but `wildcard="*foo*"` won't redirect URLs containing `foo` such as `https://localhost/?foo=true`.

How can I make it work for wildcards other than "*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it following https://serverfault.com/questions/386573/how-to-redirect-an-specific-url-with-specific-variables-in-iis.

It uses the UrlRewrite module instead of HttpRedirect.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="MyRule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^folder/Default.aspx$" />
          <action 
              type="Redirect" 
              url="folder/Default.aspx?&amp;variable1=ffff&amp;variable2=gggg" 
              appendQueryString="false" 
              redirectType="Found" /> 

          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" 
                 pattern="^&amp;variable1=eeee&amp;variable2=aaa$" />

            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" 
                 pattern="^variable1=eeee&amp;variable2=aaa$" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```